# Handling the current version of Data-tier Application in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-tier-applications

I have some problems with tracking versions of my DACs. I was unable to see the current version of database. Luckily I found this post:
[How do I find the current version of a SQL Server data-tier application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331782/how-do-i-find-the-current-version-of-a-sql-server-2008-data-tier-application)

The second answer did the trick, now I can see the current version using SQL statement:

```
select instance_name,type_version from msdb.dbo.sysdac_instances
```

Now I am able to see current version and version of new dacpac but in very ugly way. I still have some questions/uncertainties.

1. For some reason, I don't see Data-tier Applications under Management in SSMS. I was only founding discussions about this for SQL 2008 R2 so I'm not sure is that abandoned in SQL 2012 or I did something wrong.
2. When upgrading Data-tier Application in SSMS, I can only see dacpac version when reaching Summary step in upgrade wizard. When I select new dacpac in Select Package step, I expect to see the version and description of selected dacpac in the wizard below (as stated on numerous tutorials) but nothing appears. Even in summary step I can't see the version of the current DAC database which was the case in 2008 R2 according to the images I found in those tutorials.
3. Is there any way to handle version comparing a bit better than this, like showing the current version and new version on the same place? Is there a way to display warning if you are trying to upgrade using dacpac with same or lower version number?

Thx

marko