# Is there a replacement for DacStore in DacFx 3.0?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dac

In older versions of DacFx, there was a DacStore class that could be used to retrieve (for example) the version of a DAC package that is currently installed. How does one do this with DacFx 3.0? Should we continue to use the older classes for this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be8173e9-12ca-4b5a-abe6-7011bc41971c/upgrading-dacpacs-with-dacfx-30-api-how-to-inspect-current-dac-version-of-an-existing-database?forum=ssdt) there isn't a way to use the API to get the current installed version. :(
See also [Upgrading DACPACs with DACFx 3.0 API - How to inspect current DAC version of an existing database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499866/upgrading-dacpacs-with-dacfx-3-0-api-how-to-inspect-current-dac-version-of-an)

I have put an example of how to get the version programatically (using SQL Query) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30471951/9976